# guide/information on building an offline mapping Android application using nutiteq

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation, geospatial, nutiteq

Does anyone have or know of any guides/tutorials/information on how to build an offline mapping Android application using nutiteq?

Comment: Nutiteq does provide a sample app on github for v2.x. https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d. Latest v3.x you need to sign up at https://developer.nutiteq.com

Comment: Technically you don't even need to sign up for the guides and docs for 3.x. for offline base maps part see https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/offline-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what data you want to map. Assuming you use latest Nutiteq Maps SDK 3.x:

- For offline **base maps part** see [Nutiteq developer portal offline packages](http://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/offline-maps)
- For offline **map overlays** there are several options, and you can choose for example between following [Data Sources](https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/data-sources):

  1. For custom app logic use *LocalVectorDataSource* - add objects with your app
  2. For Shapefiles and other GIS file/DB formats try *OGRVectorDataSource*
  3. You can implement *custom Data Source* for more advanced cases
  4. Nutiteq helps you to create own *in-house server connection* setup

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very helpful. All thats needed for my application is a very simple base map. Ideally of the whole world if it's possible to store that much data on an SD card

Comment: Whole world currently takes about 33 GB, but we are working on to reduce it. Can you mark the answer as "accepted" here please?